# Correct place to store key pairs for SSH authentication with VPS (Cygwin and Linux)

Tags: linux, ssh, ssh-keys, cygwin

I am using Cygwin on windows 10 to try and ssh into my Linux server for the first time. I have a public and private key pair called `whm_rsa` and `whm_rsa.pub` in `user/user/.ssh` on my local computer.

Using WHM I have imported the key pair with 'manage roots SSH keys' and authorized the public_key.

The `user`@***.***.  I am trying to log into is a sub-account of root.

I have also logged into the CPanel for the sub-account and added the key pair and authorized the public key.

Below is the log could someone show me where I have gone wrong?

```
$ ssh name@*** -v -v -v
    OpenSSH_7.5p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2k  26 Jan 2017
    debug2: resolving "***.**.*" port 22
    debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
    debug1: Connecting to ***.**.* [***.**.*] port 22.
    debug1: Connection established.
    debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
    debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
    debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
    debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
    debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
    debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
    debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
    debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
    debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
    debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
    debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
    debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
    debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
    debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
    debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
    debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
    debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.5
    debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.6.1
    debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.6.1 pat OpenSSH_6.6.1* compat 0x04000000
    debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
    debug1: Authenticating to ***.**.*:22 as 'name'
    debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/user/.ssh/known_hosts"
    debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/user/.ssh/known_hosts:2
    debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from ***.**.*
    debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@opensshdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
    debug3: send packet: type 20
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
    debug3: receive packet: type 20
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
    debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
    debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp12,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha
    debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-niecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-
    debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@opens
    debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@opens
    debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.om,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
    debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.om,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
    debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
    debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
    debug2: languages ctos:
    debug2: languages stoc:
    debug2: first_kex_follows 0
    debug2: reserved 0
    debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
    debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellmanlman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
    debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
    debug2: ciphers ctos: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,c8-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
    debug2: ciphers stoc: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,c8-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
    debug2: MACs ctos: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-0-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@o@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
    debug2: MACs stoc: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-0-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@o@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
    debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
    debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
    debug2: languages ctos:
    debug2: languages stoc:
    debug2: first_kex_follows 0
    debug2: reserved 0
    debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
    debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
    debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
    debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
    debug3: send packet: type 30
    debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
    debug3: receive packet: type 31
    debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:tUFGb9yC/wlQC5JMGedvPz5GxjMb+6bKgY05b1qkWMc
    debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/user/.ssh/known_hosts"
    debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/user/.ssh/known_hosts:2
    debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from ***.**.*
    debug1: Host '***.**.*' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
    debug1: Found key in /home/user/.ssh/known_hosts:2
    debug3: send packet: type 21
    debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
    debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
    debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
    debug3: receive packet: type 21
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
    debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
    debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
    debug2: key: /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa (0x2005f510)
    debug2: key: /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa (0x0)
    debug2: key: /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa (0x0)
    debug2: key: /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519 (0x0)
    debug3: send packet: type 5
    debug3: receive packet: type 6
    debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
    debug3: send packet: type 50
    debug3: receive packet: type 51
    debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic
    debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic
    debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
    debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
    debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
    debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
    debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
    debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa
    debug3: send_pubkey_test
    debug3: send packet: type 50
    debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
    debug3: receive packet: type 51
    debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic
    debug1: Trying private key: /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa
    debug3: no such identity: /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory
    debug1: Trying private key: /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa
    debug3: no such identity: /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory
    debug1: Trying private key: /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519
    debug3: no such identity: /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519: No such file or directory
    debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
    debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
    Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
```

Comment: "Sub-account of root"? Things that would be useful (Assuming server is running OpenSSH) (All from the server): /etc/ssh/sshd_config, the SSH logs (possibly with debugging), checks that ~/.ssh/authorized_keys contains the correct public keys, permissions for the home directory, ~/.ssh and ~/.ssh/authorized_keys... (SSH is using the key from /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa in this case)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use a private key called `whm_rsa` in the `.ssh` directory, you need to pass `-i ~/.ssh/whm_rsa` to your SSH client. (The keys it will try by default all start with `id_`)

(On Windows, PuTTY might be easier to deal with than OpenSSH under Cygwin...)

Comment: Thanks this might have been my problem, will check it out asap.

Comment: I'm assuming `bash`, which will expand `~` to your home directory. Also, if you decide on PuTTY instead, keys needs to be converted... (This can be done in PuTTYgen)